# git log what does ".../{ => Folder}/..." mean?

Tags: git, version-control, git-log

I was looking at a git log of a heavy branch-coordinated repo ( lots of merging and branching ) and when I ran my handy `git log` alias: `git log --stat --pretty=short --graph`

I see this weird syntax:

```
| | |  application/client/app/Admin/Templates/index.tsx                            |   2 +-
| | |  application/client/app/Awards/Templates/Create.tsx                          | 126 ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

# here
| | |  application/client/app/Awards/{ => Templates}/Templates.scss                |   0
| | |  application/client/app/Awards/{ => Templates}/Templates.tsx                 |  12 ++---

| | |  application/client/app/components/DataTable/IndeterminateCheckbox/index.tsx |  10 ++--
| | |  application/client/app/components/DataTable/index.tsx                       | 258 ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++--------------------------------
| | |  application/client/app/components/DataTable/styles.scss                     |  96 +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++------
| | |  application/client/app/components/DropDownMenu/DropDownMenu.scss            |  26 +++++-----
| | |  application/client/app/components/DropDownMenu/index.tsx                    |  56 +++++++++++-----------
| | |  application/client/app/components/Header/Header.scss                        |  13 +++--
| | |  application/client/app/components/Header/index.tsx                          |  65 ++++++++++++++-----------
| | |  application/client/app/components/Inputs/Inputs.scss                        |  74 ++++++++++++++++++----------
| | |  application/client/app/components/Inputs/index.tsx                          |  58 +++++++++++++---------
```

The git diff isn't any help, I think it's a sub folder replace? Not sure.

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually from `git diff --stat`, which the `--stat` option to `git log --stat` invokes.

> The git diff isn't any help, I think it's a sub folder replace? Not sure.

The output you are looking at *is* from `git diff` (as built into `git log`), and you're correct.  This is a shorthand way of showing folder (directory) name changes when summarizing the difference between some commit *L* (placed on the left) and some other commit *R* (placed on the right).  Since `git log` is comparing a parent-and-child commit pair, the *L* (left-side) commit is the parent—the old commit that comes just before the child—and the *R* (right-side) commit is the child that comes just after that parent.  Git was able to match up a file named:

```
application/client/app/Awards/Templates.scss
```

in the *L* commit against one named:

```
application/client/app/Awards/Templates/Templates.scss
```

in the *R* commit.

Note that you can run:

```
git diff --stat <left-side-commit-ID> <right-side-commit-ID>
```

yourself, to get the same kind of output; in this case you can pick any two commits you like.  Let's say some very old commit has hash ID `a123456` and some recent commit has hash ID `07fbdad`.  Then:

```
git diff --stat a123456 07fbdad
```

will show you this kind of summary of what it takes to change the contents of `a123456` to match the contents of `07fbdad`.  This works because each commit has a *full and complete snapshot of every file* that Git knew about at the time you, or whoever, made the commit.

For commits *before* the left-side one (e.g., the parent of the parent), the file is likely to have the older name.  For commits *after* it, the file is likely to have the newer name.

(In a sense, Git doesn't really have folders at all.  The files are just stored with very long names that include embedded slashes.  But Git knows that your *operating system* requires that these be treated as folder-and-file names, i.e., a series of slash-separated name *components*, so it tries to accommodate that, even though Git has a more flexible internal file naming system.)